# How to get file extension name excluding file tail?

Tags: tcl

Is there any way to get path only for file?
For example,

```
    /u/m_n/hi.txt
```

if i use file tail it'll give me

```
   hi.txt
```

I want only

```
   /u/m_n/
```

I tried with file rootname, bit it give output till '.', like this

```
  /u/m_n/hi
```

Yup, I think it's file dirname, got it.
Sorry for spam.

Answer (score 2):

You shuld use:

```
file dirname "/u/m_n/hi.txt"
```

And it returns:

```
/u/m_n
```

As you asked.

If you want the file extension as you wrote in the title, use the *file extension*

```
file extension "/u/m_n/hi.txt"
```

It will return:

```
.txt
```

Comment: The commands `file tail`, `file extension`, and `file dirname` form a group of related operations; `file tail` gets everything after the last directory separator, `file extension` gets the last `.` and everything after it, and `file dirname` gets everything up to the last directory separator (and does something sensible if there's no directory separator).